# Defining an Excel cell name from dictionary keys

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to input data into a series of named Excel sheets e.g `CellName1` as opposed to `A1`, based on a key in a dictionary. The code I'm using is seen bellow:

```
snCells = {}
for item1  in defVars:
    if item1.find("LFDef"):
        ws = wLF
        snCells.update({item1:ws.Range[item1](1,1)})
    elif item1.find("UFDef"):
        ws = wLF
        snCells.update({item1:ws.Range["%s" % item1](1,1)})
    else:
        ws = wST
        snCells.update({item1:ws.Range["%s"% item1](1,1)})
```

where:

```
ex = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
wb = ex.ActiveWorkbook
ws = wb.ActiveSheet
wUF = wb.Sheets(1).Select
wLF = wb.Sheets(2).Select
wST = wb.Sheets(4).Select
```

Range should define the cell that Python is selecting in Excel, however I keep getting errors saying that range has no attribute. Is there any way of resolving this error?

Comment: Your indentation seems wrong

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 'Range' is the cell I am trying to access. in an example I have that works for inputting data to excel they use:
'ws.Range["F16"](1,1)'where 'ws' is defined as above.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu indentation has been fixed. It is correct in my text editor, it was just the way it copied it across. The error still remains the same claiming that 'Range' has no attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on which version of excel you are using, however in 2010 the [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196817%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object has a [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839264%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property.

Without trying, it looks like you should call the `Name` object and use the [`Name.RefersToRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834918%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property to get the `Range` object you are after.

A really useful bookmark when working with excel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846392%28v=office.14%29.aspx

It should be something like this:

```
snCells.update({item1: wb.Names(item1).RefersToRange()})
```

`wb.Names(item1).RefersToRange()` returns a tuple of tuples with the data you are after. Say if you range is "A1:B2" it would look like this:

```
((A1 value, A2 value),
 (B1 value, B2 value))
```

If you only want specific values from your range, e.g. A1, you could do: `wb.Names("item1").RefersToRange()[0][0]`. The first [0] gives you the first tuple, i.e. the first row, and the second [0] gives you the first value in this row.

Note that `Names` sits in the workbook object `wb` as opposed to the sheet object `ws` which I suggested before.

If all this talk about objects and so on is confusing, it might help to read up on object orientated concepts. The thing is that it sounds a lot harder than it really is. While this might be horribly wrong from the perspective of a computer scientist, I think of object orientation primarily as a way of organising things; pretty close to a folder structure on the hard drive:

The excel api gives you access to a lot of functionality. The first object you use is the workbook. This has a number of properties and methods. wb.Name returns the filename, whereas wb.Names gives you access to all the named ranges and/or cells you have defined. Those cells have more properties which for instance return the values in the range the name refers to. Something like this:

```
- wb
    - Name: Returns filename # <--- a property available for the wb object
    - Names( name ): Returns reference to the range called 'name'
        - .RefersToRange(): Returns tuple with values of the range   # <--- a function available under the Names object
        - ...... (much more in here) ........
    - ...... (much more in here, i.e. for the wb object) ........
```

Comment: apologies but i am a total beginner with this stuff and i'm not entirely certain what you mean? would you be able to type out what you described in code?

Comment: just tried it myself, although the `Name.RefersToRange(item1)` method didn't work just using `snCells.update({item1: ws.Names(item1)(1,1)})` seemed to move me on to the next error. the latest error to show is 
`COMException: Exception from HREASULT:0x800A03EC in file "file location"`

Comment: Hmmm... just for finding out what happens, try what `ws.Name.RefersToRange("AnActualReference")` returns, i.e. before your loop, do `print ws.Name.RefersToRange("AnActualReference")`. This should say that it is a range object. If not, double check that "ActualReference" is the correct name for a range in the spreadsheet. Which version of excel are you using? 2010 or another one?

Comment: just tried it and i get the output
`MissingMemberException: 'str' object has no atribute 'RefersToRange' in file "...."`

Comment: @Sam I updated my answer and fixed the 'typos' from yesterday... I should remember not to answer questions before bedtime... I also tried to explain the first part a bit better. Let me know if it's useful